# ansible playbook when condition for replay

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, ansible

is there any option for the replay the play in the playbook? I want to write ansible playbook like below. I want to run play2 if any error in the play1_result and after running play1 if play2 is a success

```
tasks:
  - name: play1
    ...
    register: play1_result

  - name: play2
    ...
    when: 'FAILED' in play1.stderr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "to run play2 if any error in the play1_result"

an option would be to use [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html)

```
- block:
    - name: play1
      ...
  rescue:
    - name: play2
      ...
```

> to replay the play1 after the rescue section ran the play2

```
  rescue:
    - name: play2
      ...
    - name: play1
      ...
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for the answer I want to replay the play1 after the rescue section ran the play2. Probably, this rescue did not provide my condition.